# Basic example of Camera upload to iCloud Drive Folder (with Swift in Xcode)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, icloud, icloud-drive

I am currently looking for a really basic example of a Camera upload to a iCloud Drive Folder (with Swift in Xcode)...

I am looking to take a photo with the camera and upload/sync the picture to a folder in iCloud (Folder for my App).

I have searched around and cannot find any really basic examples.

Any one have a example or really good reference...

Many Thanks StackOverflowers in advance...